# Tkinter Button - How to get the values and display it using a single module for different Buttons

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a GUI, where I have placed three buttons for selecting a file. When I click the button it browse for a file and display the selected file path and I am trying to do it with a single browse function since the operation is same. I am bit confused to how I should proceed . Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

Browse_Files.py

```
from tkinter import filedialog
def Browse_File():
     global Bfilepath
     Bfilepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Please select the required file", "*"), ("All files", "*")))

return Bfilepath
```

Main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
import fileinput
import Browse_Files
root = Tk()
root.geometry('1400x800')
root.title('Dr Configuration')

Heading = Label(root, font=('Times New Roman',50,'bold'),text = "Arxml 
Configuration Tool").place(x=300,y=25)
BasepathLabel = Label(root,font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'),text = " Base 
arxml").place(x=200,y=150)
NewpathLabel= Label(root,font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'),text = " 
New/Unedited arxml").place(x=200,y=250)
InterfaceLabel = Label(root,font=('Times New Roman',20,'bold'),text = " 
Interface_File").place(x=200,y=350)


BpathtoDisp = StringVar(None)
BpathEntry = Entry(root,font=('Times New Roman',18),textvariable= 
BpathtoDisp,justify='left',width=48).place(x=500,y=150)

NpathtoDisp = StringVar(None)
NpathEntry = Entry(root,font=('Times New Roman',18),textvariable= 
NpathtoDisp,justify='left',width=48).place(x=500,y=250)

InterPathtoDisp = StringVar(None)
InterPathEntry = Entry(root,font=('Times New Roman',18),textvariable= 
NpathtoDisp,justify='left',width=48).place(x=500,y=350)


button1 = Button(root,text="...",height=1,width=3,command=lambda:Browse_Files.Browse_File()).place(x=1100,y=150)
button2 = Button(root,text="...",height=1,width=3,command=lambda:Browse_Files.Browse_File()).place(x=1100,y=250)
button3 = Button(root,text="...",height=1,width=3,command=lambda:Browse_Files.Browse_File()).place(x=1100,y=350)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a class that contains the functionality to have a button, open a file dialog, store it and make it available to other parts of the program.

I have a similar widget that I use in many different programs

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class FileSelect(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master,label="",**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.configure(**kw)
        self.file = StringVar()

        self.Label = Label(self, text=label)
        self.Label.config(width=10,anchor=E)
        self.filenamebox = Entry(self,text=self.file)
        self.filenamebox.config(width=50)
        self.btnBrowse = Button(self,text='Browse',command=self.browse_file)
        self.btnBrowse.config(width=10)
        self.Label.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=5,sticky=E)
        self.filenamebox.grid(row=0,column=1,pady=5)
        self.btnBrowse.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=5,padx=5)

    def browse_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('All File','*.*')])
        self.file.set(filename)

    def get_filename(self):
        return self.file.get()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Example Widget")

    fileSelect1 = FileSelect(root,label="My File 1")
    fileSelect1.grid()
    fileSelect2 = FileSelect(root,label="My File 2")
    fileSelect2.grid()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In your code if you want the value of the file selected use

```
fileSelect1.get_filename()
```

EDIT: I've created a new version that is only a Button 'with memory' to remember which item was selected by the file dialog. This will allow you to place using the `place` geometry manager (which I don't recommend). Its not complete but you should get the idea.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class FileSelectButton(Button):
    def __init__(self,master,**kw):
        Button.__init__(self,master,text='Browse',command=self.browse_file,width=10,**kw)
        self.file = StringVar()

    def browse_file(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('All File','*.*')])
        self.file.set(filename)

    def get_filename(self):
        return self.file.get()


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('1400x800')
    root.title("Example Widget")

    Label(root, font=('Times New Roman',50,'bold'),text = "Label1").place(x=200,y=150)
    fileSelect1 = FileSelectButton(root)
    fileSelect1.place(x=500,y=150)

    Label(root, font=('Times New Roman',50,'bold'),text = "Label2").place(x=200,y=250)
    fileSelect2 = FileSelectButton(root)
    fileSelect2.place(x=500,y=250)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: But by this way I could not able to adjust the position of the Buttons. If I tried to change those are getting returned to its original position

Comment: I don't ever use place but this doesn't stop you from editing my code to use `.place` instead of `.grid` to relocate the buttons. The functionality behind the FileSelect class won't change if you do this.

Comment: Yeah I tried using place but I could not see anything , Only I can see is empty frame. I tried changing grid positions , also it is not allowing me to do it.

Comment: This is why I don't use place.... Doesn't work well when you try to create multiple instances of a complex widget. Perhaps you could raise a separate question about placing buttons etc inside frames.